# How to Create raw printer file(prn) from bmp

Tags: c#

I want to make raw printer command from a BMP Image for hp laserjet printer 1018 in C# 
and then send to printer as prn file. pay attention please, that I dont want to use printer driver that released by hp company.

Comment: do you want it in PCL format?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 distinct things that happen when you print from a Windows application. The first one, providing a device context and rendering the output, requires a printer driver. The second one, streaming the resulting document, does not. You can configure a printer driver to print to a file, but you cannot create print output without a printer driver. The printer driver converts the BMP image into something that the printer understands.

You can use another PCL printer driver for that matter, configure it to print to file, then take the file and send it to your printer. But you cannot generate the file without a printer driver. Trying to do that amounts to writing your own printer driver of sorts, which you can do. Any [PCL reference](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/bpl13205/bpl13205.pdf) will show you what commands the printer understands.

Comment: from mostafa : my printer does not support PCL commands and is a Host-based printer.

Comment: Then I don't understand your issue. What printer do you have? You either need a printer driver in order to use the Windows print system for generating a print file, or you need to write your own code the generates the print file. If you are asking about the latter, you still need to know your printer's command set. This is true for any printer, whether it is PCL or a host printer that understand AFPDS or IPDS spool files.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://forums.systeminetwork.com/isnetforums/showthread.php?t=105941